# Data recovery of file with special file extension

Tags: 12.10, data-recovery, dd

This question might seem's to be similar but it is not, what I want to ask is as follows,

I have a flash drive. It had files in it which are very important to me. But accidentally it was formatted.
Yes there are tools to recover data like **Foremost**, **Scalpel**. And I used them to recover my deleted data, but my problem wasn't solved. These tools are best to recover file with well known formats, like jpg, png, gif, pdf etc.

The data that I actually wanted back was present in an hidden folder. And in case of Ubuntu a hidden folder's name starts with a '.' (dot). Moreover the files in it were images but with the extension '.hid'.

eg: files with name like 'MyPhoto.jpg.hid' were present in that hidden folder.

I first created an image (.img) file of my flash drive using the '**dd**' , and tried to recover the data using Foremost and Scalpel. Though I got all the file with popular file extensions, but didn't get those file with '.hid' extension.

Is there a way to recover those files with that **special** ('.hid') file extension which were present in that hidden folder.

Please help me out! Those files are very IMPORTANT to Me!

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the option to "show hidden files" in your the file browser.

The files might actually be there!

I have personally used Testdisk & Photo Recovery to successfully restore information for friends on several occassions.

Depending on what Ubuntu version you are running the option to view hidden files is either in "View" at the menu bar (Earlier versions) or "Files -Preferences" in the menu bar on 13.04.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but that is not my case. All those hidden folder are also deleted, so even if I use the "show hidden files" option those deleted folders wont be visible.